# Creating an array of columns from an array of column names in data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I create an array of columns from an array of column names in dataflow?
The following creates an array of sorted columns with and exception of the last column:

```
sort(slice(columnNames(), 1, size(columnNames()) - 1), compare(#item1, #item2))
```

I want to get an array of the columns for this array of column names. I tried this:

```
toString(byNames(sort(slice(columnNames(), 1, size(columnNames()) - 1), compare(#item1, #item2))))
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Column name function 'byNames' does not accept column or argument parameters
```

Please can anyone help me with a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update--**

It seems using **ColumnNames()** in any way (directly or assigning it to a parameter) seems to be leading to error. As at runtime on Spark it is fed to the **byNames()** function. Due to unavailability of a way to re-introduce as parameter or assign variable in Data Flow directly, see below which works for me.

Have empty string array type parameter in DataFLow

[image]

Use sha2 function as usual in derived column with parameter  `sha2(256,byNames($cols))`

[image]

Create pipeline, there use getMetadata to get Structure from which you can get column names.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For each column, inside ForEach activity append to a variable.

[image]

Next, connect to DataFLow and pass the variable containing Column names.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The documentation for the byNames function states '**Computed inputs are not supported but you can use parameter substitutions'**.  This explains why you should use a parameter as input to create the array used in the byNames function:

Example: Where `$cols` parameter hold the list of columns.

```
sha2(256,byNames(split($cols,',')))
```

You can use computed columns names as input by creating the array prior to using in function. Instead of creating the expression in-line in the function call, set the column values in a parameter prior and then use it in your function directly afterwards.

For a parameter `$cols` of type array:

```
$cols = sort(slice(columnNames(), 1, size(columnNames()) - 1), compare(#item1, #item2))

toString(byNames(sort(slice($cols, compare(#item1, #item2))))
```

Refer: [byNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#:%7E:text=functions%20%28toDate,%20toString,%20...%29.-,Column%20names%20known%20at%20design%20time%20should%20be%20addressed%20just%20by%20their%20name.%20Computed%20inputs%20are%20not%20supported%20but%20you%20can%20use%20parameter%20substitutions.,-toString%28byNames%28%5B%27parent)

Comment: I followed your advice and it still doesn't work. Currently, I'm sorting the names of the columns in a dataflow parameter and then using the parameter of sorted names to get the columns using byNames but I'm still getting the same error. 

For the Dataflow Parameter; `dropLeft(reduce(sort(slice(columnNames(), 1, size(columnNames()) - 1), compare(#item1, #item2)), '', #acc + ',' + #item, #result), 1)`
Derived Column Expression; `sha2(256, dropLeft(reduce(array(toString(byNames(split($parameter2, ',')))), '', #acc + '|' + #item, #result), 1))`

Comment: I've tried, inserting array literally gets the result but if we use functions to get them dynamically, byNames() throws error as it requires only array and getting column names dynamically in a array seems to be tricky. Please check one way I found as updated above

Comment: I tried your updated solution and although it worked as presented it still does not work for what I'm trying to do. I need to sort the array of column names which you did not include. When I try sorting and then generating a hash of the sort columns I still get the error. If there was a way I can sort the array prior to the data flow maybe that would work. That is, if I can pass in a sorted array to my data flow. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a way to do that.

Comment: You can use Azure functions activity to spin a server less python or powershell env where you can sort the array passed from forEach activity output and capture the sorted array from function activity response to send to Dataflow as parameter.

Comment: let me know if you need that to be explained in answer as well

Comment: Thank you for all the help with this. I'll look into using Azure functions and I'll let you know if I need further details. If you can think of another solution that doesn't involve using another azure resource please let me know. I don't want to introduce additional resources if not absolutely necessary.